# Display observable error message to our user

Tags: angular, error-handling, ionic4

I have the following method in Login.ts

```
login(form) {
  this.authService.login(form.value).subscribe(
  result => { // your result from observer.next() in auth.service
    // success
    this.router.navigateByUrl('tabs');
  },
  error => { // your error from observer.error() in auth.servi
    // I wish to display my error message here
);
}
```

And this calls the following method in authService.ts

```
 login(postData: User): Observable<any> {
this.presentLoading('Attempting to Login');
return new Observable(observer => {
  this.http.post(this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS + `/login`, postData)
    .pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        this.loadingController.dismiss();
        return throwError(error); // if you catch any errors, pass them (rethrow) to the error block
      })
     )
     .subscribe(
       result => {
        this.loadingController.dismiss();
        this.UserIsAuthenticated = true;
        this.setUserID(postData);
        observer.next(result); // if you receive a result, pass to register function in register.page.ts
        observer.complete(); // close the observable
       },
       error => {
        this.loadingController.dismiss();
        alert(error);
        observer.error(error); // if you receive an error, pass error to register function
        observer.complete(); // close the observable
        }
      );
    });

}
```

If an error occurs in the login method i would like to notify the user with an alert with a detailed description of the error. However i am unsure on how to display this message to the user in the Login.ts file in die are i have indicated with my comments. I have tried

```
alert(error);
```

which simply returns null as well as

```
alert(error.value);
```

but neither of these work properly. Any advice on how to achieve this.

Comment: If you console log the error, what does it output? What is it’s structure?

Comment: It simply says null at the moment or {object:Object}

Comment: side note: be cautious about how detailed that message is. Generally login systems are vague about the error so hackers can't use the the information to confirm which accounts exist and which part of the login failed.

Comment: Will do all i say is login failed, no further detail given

Comment: @SteveRogers, what @AlexanderStaroselsky said: is your error an object like: `{ error: 'error message' }`or do you receive a string? Just inspect what you receive from your server and adjust the function appropriately ...